# sizeof char array inside an union is not printing correctly

Tags: c, sizeof, unions

```
union u
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char c[10];
};
int main()
{
    union u abc;
    printf("\n%d",sizeof(abc));
}
```

Output: 12
I expect the output to be 10.sizeof(char) is 1. So for 10 i expect it to be 10. Can someone explain me why do we get 12.

Comment: There be padding.

Comment: Title: 'sizeof char array', (the char c[10]).  Code: 'sizeof(abc)', (the union).   Why claim one thing and then demonstrate another?

Comment: Are you asking about the size of the array (title) or the size of the union (code)?

Comment: To print the "sizeof char array inside an union", `printf("%zu\n",sizeof(abc.c));`

Answer (score 2):

This because probably at least one between `float` or `int` data type has 4 bytes alignment requirement. So the `struct` gets 2 bytes of padding (so that `sizeof(struct u) % 4 == 0`).

You can use `__attribute__((packed))` or similar features if your compiler supports them to avoid padding but it's not convenient unless you have preexisting data to conform with. Think about the fact that an array of packed `struct u` elements will have unaligned `float`/`int` members.

Comment: "This because float (and int) have 4 bytes alignment requirement." --> Could be just one of the two have the requirement especially with a 16-bit `int`.

Comment: @chux: yes, on most non embedded platforms both will mostly be 4 bytes, on embedded platforms it really depends. I'm unsure about half precision floating, surely used in computer graphics but no clues which embedded architectures could use it as a direct replacement for `float`.